# Fully Qualified Type Resolution in .NET

Tags: .net, sharepoint, assembly-resolution, fusion

Simple question (comes up in **SharePoint 2010**, but that's not really relevant).

How does:

```
<add name="LdapMembershipProvider" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
```

...resolve when the actual type (**LdapMembershipProvider**) is only found in the **Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles** assembly and not in the **Microsoft.Office.Server** assembly?

Both are GAC registered.

Does **Fusion** probe other assemblies, even when a fully qualified type is specified?

Comment: What is the public key token of both assemblies?

Comment: The public key token is the same for both assemblies: 71e9bce111e9429c.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly binding redirection?

[MSDN - Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(VS.71).aspx) ?

> You can redirect an assembly binding
>   reference to another version of an
>   assembly by using entries in the
>   application or machine configuration
>   files. You can redirect references to
>   .NET Framework assemblies, third-party
>   assemblies, or assemblies of your own
>   application.

Comment: Hi Ryan; I don't think it's related to binding redirection (used to redirect to different version of the assembly, not a different assembly all together).

Comment: Hmm - I had assumed that you could do type as well as version. Downvoting my own answer! Time to crack out the Fusion log viewer I think
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx

+ Suzanne Cooke is the first blogger to go to for this elbows deep in the internals stuff.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the public key token is actually pointing to the correct assembly and its ignoring the assembly name?

I was reading the following MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.aspx

The excerpt that sounds suspicious:

> It is possible to specify a public key
>   and a KeyPair with inconsistent
>   values. This can be useful in
>   developer scenarios. In this case, the
>   public key retrieved with GetPublicKey
>   specifies the correct public key,
>   while the KeyPair specifies the public
>   and private keys used during
>   development. **When the runtime detects
>   a mismatch between the KeyPair and the
>   public key, it looks up in the
>   registry the correct key that matches
>   the public key.**

Not sure.  One behaviour that immediately springs to mind, but I cannot confirm is that if it fails to find the type in the assembly *you* specify in configuration, it tries to find it through your project references.